# What's wrong with rails activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

With this code:

```
candidates = Challenge.joins(:projectmilestone).where("challenges.id in (?) and projectmilestones.user_id = ?", c.subtree_ids, assignee.id)
logger.debug "candidates: #{candidates.count}"
```

I get this into my logs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "challenges" INNER JOIN "projectmilestones" ON "projectmilestones"."id" = "challenges"."projectmilestone_id" WHERE (challenges.id in (1122) and projectmilestones.user_id = 123)
Candidate projectmilestones: 0
```

When I run the query straight in the database, the result is 1
Why does Activerecord tells me that the result = 0?

Please note that when I remove "and projectmilestones.user_id" from the code, then it performs right.

This has been driving me crazy for a couple of hours...

Comment: Does the challenges or projectmilestones table have a "count" column?

Comment: If the very same query returns correct results when run directly from the database, might it be the case that you are actually querying against a different database (different environment)? Try it in `rails c` and then in `rails db`.

Comment: If you log `"candidates: #{candidates.count}"` why it shows `projectmilestones: 0`?

Comment: Hi, I've the same issue in rails c and rails db. None of my table have a "count" column. I don't know why it shows projectmilestones instead of candidates (I've changed the code again since then) but I confirm the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Wrong SQL statement: **challenges.id in (1122)**

If c.subtree_ids returns array, then:

```
c.subtree_ids.join(", ")
```

Comment: I wish it could be that easy but as I wrote above, the sql statement is correct. (look at my logs + I checked it on the db)

Comment: i dont think so... Correct statement is challenges.id in (1,1,2,2)

Comment: it's (1122), there is only 1 in this case

Comment: So thats weird for me too. )

Answer (score 0):

I've got it: I changed the user_id before triggering the above query but I saved it afterwards...

This is why, when running the code, it was incorrect but when cross-checking, it was ok...

Nothing was wrong with rails, it was with wrong with me... Sorry and thanks for your help!